# Combine two regex together

Tags: regex, bash

I have this expression from a `ps ax` list that I want to parse:

```
183838 ? myprocess -uuid 0f6309e3-bee2-4747-b76d-7aaf4d0f074e serial=802e7fd9-a2ab-e411-8000-001e67ca95b2
```

I want to match the process id (`183838`) AND the uuid expression (`0f6309e3-bee2-4747-b76d-7aaf4d0f074e`).

I have the two regexes that match each of them:

```
# PID
([0-9]*)
# UUID
(?<=uuid).([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})
```

But I can't find how to combine them together to have this as result with `sed`:

```
183838 0f6309e3-bee2-4747-b76d-7aaf4d0f074e
```

`awk` is not an option since it must be column number independent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `|` or operator in regex in between your two regex expressions to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Bash uses POSIX ERE, and you have a PCRE with a lookbehind. If you need PCRE, `grep -P` is an option, combined with `-o`, an option to pring only matched parts of the matched line:

```
$ ps ax | grep -oP '(^[0-9]+)|(?<=uuid )([-0-9a-f]{36})' | paste -sd' '
183838 0f6309e3-bee2-4747-b76d-7aaf4d0f074e
```

(We combine multiple lines here with `paste`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sort of matching with *capturing groups*. These are enclosed by `\(` and `\)` in sed. In the replacement, `\1` is replaced by whatever matched the content of the first capturing group, and so on.

So to translate your input string:

```
$ ps ax | grep -- '-uuid' | sed 's/\([0-9]*\).* -uuid \([0-9a-f-]*\).*/\1 \2/'
183838 0f6309e3-bee2-4747-b76d-7aaf4d0f074
```

I've used the "-uuid" as an anchor to locate the right part of the string, allowing a shorter and more relaxed pattern for the uuid itself. But you can adapt this to your own requirements.